# JointJS paper coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I have a pan controller in my application that scrolls the paper. How can I get the coordinates of what is showing to see if an element is entirely on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to know the coordinates (x, y, width, height) of the paper element. `x`, `y` could be the `scrollLeft`, `scrollTop`. `width` and `height` is the dimension of the element. Lets call this "client coordinates". Client coordinates are the same as jointJs graph coordinates in case there are no transformations on paper (e.g scale). Otherwise you need to do a conversion between client coordinates and graph coordinates.

Methods like `paper.clientToLocalPoint(clientX, clientY)` or `paper.clientToLocalRect(clientX, clientY, width, height)` can do the job.

Or, in the RappidJS you can simply call the `getVisibleArea` on the `joint.ui.PaperScroller` plugin

Comment: for me , the clientToLocalPoint was in window["paper"].paper . thanks.